# GitKraken won't push, but won't let me sign in

Tags: git, gitkraken

I have a Git Repository that I have been pushing and pulling from for a long while. Every time I tried in a new session it would require me to sign in to be allowed to push and pull the repo, however suddenly today the repo will always pull up an error:

`Push Failed: master unexpected HTTP status code: 400`

Which I deduce is because it isn't asking me to sign in before I do the pull. I currently don't have any saved credentials on my GitKraken account so that isn't a problem, and restarting both GitKraken and my laptop hasn't fixed it.

For reference the last successful push that I did happened 2 days ago and nothing has changed regarding the project and or my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did create a ticket to gitkraken and I got answer from my ticket. You can see on my screenshot. I am still waiting a update but they didn't deliver

[image: Screen shot]
*EDIT 19.08.2019*

My problem was in VSTS repository. I have no idea they did fix in 6.1.1 or new version. I changed my git config to SSH connect URL.
You can find your config file in .git folder in your repo folder. You will see like this code of part in config file;

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = username:token@proje_name.visualstudio.com:blablablabla...
```

You will change with your ssh url like

```
[remote "origin"]
    url =projects@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/projects/blablala...
```

You musn't forget you should a create ssh token with gitKraken to VSTS

Comment: Any update on this? I am also experiencing this error in Gitkraken 6.1.1 when using a VSTS repository.

Comment: My problem was in VSTS repository. I have no idea they did fix in 6.1.1. I changed my git config to SSH connect URL.
You can find your config file in .git folder in your repo folder. You will see like this code of part in config file;
[remote "origin"]
 url = username:token@proje_name.visualstudio.com:blablablabla...

You will change with your ssh url like
[remote "origin"]
 url =projects@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/projects/blablala...

You musn't forget you should a create ssh token with gitKraken to VSTS

Comment: I guess SSH could be a workaround, but I really would like to keep using HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, I think It's still problem but my colleagues hasn't any problem with HTTPS in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring because you are using https authentication instead of ssh authentication. If you want to clear out old credentials

1. From the start menu search for "credential manager"
2. Select "Windows Credentials"
3. You should see your "git:https://github.com" credential [image]
4. Select the dropdown and pick edit if you want to update the credential or remove if you want gitkraken to re-prompt you for your password.

The other option would be to switch to ssh authentication. [This](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/#ssh) is guide from GitKraken on how to use/setup ssh credentials.